# Linking a domain name with 123-reg to Github Pages

Tags: github, dns

I bought a domain name on *123-reg* and I am now trying to link it to Github Pages. I am really stuck on this part.

Please could someone give me a step-by-step guide??

I've tried doing what the image attached shows [image]

Comment: The screenshot shows "www.mygithubrepository.." - you say it would be the actual name, but could you update the screenshot to that exact value? (It's presumably public, so there shouldn't be any problem in doing so.) As per [the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-www-subdomain/) it would usually be `mygithubrepository.github.io`

Comment: I've edited the original post to show it now. Hope that helps.

Comment: Right, so the problem is that you haven't followed the pattern it's said to use - you've got an extra `www` at the start, and a slash with more stuff after it. You want *just* `aicayzer.github.io`. That's all. Make sure you've set up github to handle the custom domain as per [this documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-or-removing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/) too.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the below entries  -

```
@    A       199.27.XX.XXX (ip is provided by github pages documentation.)
www  CNAME   aicayzer.github.io.
```

On doing a dig on your domain you should see below responses -

```
example.com.     3600    IN  A      199.27.XX.XXX
www.example.com. 3592    IN  CNAME  aicayzer.github.io.
```

From your screenshot -

- Remove the A record `www` entry.
- In the CNAME entry of www just add  `aicayzer.github.io.`
- Save

Comment: You need GitHub A/AAAA from [guide step 5](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site?platform=linux#configuring-an-apex-domain) if you want `*  CNAME   <user>.github.io`.  
Else remember to add `www.` to your pages custom domain.